# I want to know what is wrong with my method to_s? Why am I still getting undefined method length if that method is created right above?

Tags: ruby, calendar

This is my code and my error message from my terminal. My project is trying to print out the months of a year like the Cal in the terminal.

```
class Month
  attr_reader :month, :year

  def initialize( month, year)
    @month = month
    @year = year
  end

  def month_names
      names_of_months = {1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December'}
      return names_of_months[@month]
  end

    def length
      days_of_months  = {1 => '31', 2 => '28', 3 => '31', 4 => '30', 5 => '31', 6 => '30', 7 => '31', 8 => '31', 9 => '30', 10 => '31', 11 => '30', 12 => '31'}
      return days_of_months[@month]
  end


  def to_s
   output = "#{month_names} #{year} #{length}"
    (1.length).each do |day|
      output << day.to_s
    end
    output
  end
end
```

and error message:

```
Error:
TestMonth#test_to_s_on_march_2015:
NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for 1:Fixnum
    /Users/brandonespinoza/Desktop/code/RUBY/cal-app/lib/month.rb:22:in `to_s'
    test/test_month.rb:56:in `test_to_s_on_march_2015'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `.length` on `1`, which looks for the method `.length` on the `Fixnum` class. To use your `length` method, try replacing `1.length` with just `length`.

Comment: Just a heads up, though, you're likely to still run into problems as you'll then be calling `.each` on a string (e.g. `'31'`, `'28'`, etc.)

Comment: i added one to call January tho. How can i call January without having this problem?

Comment: Since `length` takes no arguments and simply returns `days_of_months[@month]`, you'll only get the return value for January when `@month == 1`. And you only set `@month` equal to `1` when you initialize a new object of the class `Month` with the arguments `(1, ...)`.

Comment: btw, to correct the problem I pointed out in the first comment, I think you'd want to have `(1..length.to_i).each do ...`

Comment: hmmm.. so lets see if im getting this correctly. What your saying is that i need to put 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.length?

Comment: no, you won't be able to call your `.length` method on anything but an instance of the class where it's defined. Since 1-12 aren't inherently objects of the class `Month`, that won't work. The easiest solution might just be to have your length method take a parameter, so that you could pass in each number as an argument (e.g. `length(1)` => `days_of_months(1)`.

Comment: ooh ok. Man im a still a bit confuse how to set this up. I get why im getting this error tho.